# Cheerio get element outer html

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I am using cheerio to parse html file on server side with node 6.10.2. I need to get outerHtml of each div inside document body and my code is:

```
 /* const data is valid html document (type of string)*/
 const $ = cheerio.load(data);
 let pages = $('body > div').toArray();
 console.log(pages[0]); // Elements parsed correctly
 let htmlPages = pages.map(page => $(page).html());
 console.log(htmlPages[0]); // Here I have innerHtml, not outer...
```

Problem: I'm getting string with innerHtml.
Can anybody help pls. ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Change your map func to

```
let htmlPages = pages.map(page => $.html(page));
```

according to [docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#rendering)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have easy access to the original $ object, the following also works

```
function outerHTML (element) {
    var index = element.index();
    var parent = element.parent().clone();
    var child = parent.children()[index];
    parent.empty();
    parent.append(child);
    return parent.html();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, I just got an error on the index() that its not a function:Houston we have a problem: TypeError: element.index is not a function
    at outerHTML (C:\xxxxx\cafe\locators\crawler\scanner.js:77:23)
    at GetElementContent (C:\xxxxx\cafe\locators\crawler\scanner.js:45:15)
    at Node.GetElementContent.$.children.each (C:\xxxxx\cafe\locators\crawler\scanner.js:67:7)
    at initialize.exports.each (C:\xxxxx\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\traversing.js:300:24)
    at GetElementContent (C:\xxxxx\cafe\locators\crawler\scanner.js:62:27)

Comment: This does work: function outerHTML(element) {
  $(element).each(function(index, elem) {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($.html($this));
  });
};

Comment: Seth Eden's comment works. Can you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Just get property of html element:

```
$(page).html().prop('outerHTML')
```